# sql ce to ms sql server paging query (for razor web pages)

Tags: sql

recently i read this article
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/150/Web-Pages-Efficient-Paging-Without-The-WebGrid
but my problem is that article uses sql server ce but im using MS sql server and i want to 
write this codes:

```
sql = "Select Title, ISBN, Description, FirstName, LastName, Category From Books " + 
       "Inner Join Authors on Books.AuthorId = Authors.AuthorId " + 
       "Inner Join Categories on Books.CategoryId = Categories.CategoryId " +
       "Order By BookId OFFSET @0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @1 ROWS  ONLY;";

var result = db.Query(sql, offset, pageSize);
```

now what is the same query for "Order By BookId OFFSET @0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @1 ROWS  ONLY;"
in sql server,
 and if you know another article to do this in another way thats fine too
 thank u so much guys